# NSMutableArray alloc and init not working properly

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, init, alloc

I've been coding for a while now but seem to be getting this issue regularly which never occurred before. When trying to init arrays / dictionaries they always show as empty even though I'm sure they are being initialised correctly.

[image: Screenshot of error]

This is simply an NSMutableArray which I @property (nonatomic, retain) and @synthesize. Can anyone tell me why this would be happening as I've noticed it happening in places where it wasn't before. Could this simply be the prediction/intellisense displaying incorrect information, and if so how can I fix it?

Thanks in advanced,
Elliott

Comment: Try to type `po self.pickerObjects` in console (and Enter). Xcode may not show actual info sometimes.

Comment: Heya, thanks for the tip that showed me the data, it's so annoying that happens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to type `po self.pickerObjects` in console (and Enter). Xcode may not show actual info sometimes. You code looks good, i think it's just an Xcode glitch).

Answer (score 1):

Yes I have noticed something like that. `NSLog` pickerObjects, and see what happens.

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.pickerObjects);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it is in there and I noticed this with my previous project. I just wondered if there was any way to update the intellisense (whatever its called for apple) to fix this.

Answer (score -3):

if i'm not mistaken..this is because you have your array as class property instead of instance variable

remove @property and @synthesize and call it as `pickerObjects = [........]`

to use self.pickerObjects you first need to alloc and init your view (what you're doing there is calling a class property..and you haven't inited your class)

(does that make sence?)

i'm not very good with explaining...but this is the problem..try that and see what happens

Comment: I dont think that is true, the view will be initialised anyway (hence why the loadview method is being called). It shouldn't have any implication on the actual data members of the class either I don't think. If I was using an IBOutlet and trying to rely on the view initialisation then your statement would be correct.

Comment: You are incredibly, appallingly mistaken. The code inside `viewDidLoad:` couldn't even be executing if there was no `self`. Also, the `@synthesize` directive _creates_ the ivar, and links it to the property; `self.pickerObjects` is perfectly correct.